# Randomness algorithm in python that integrates a demi-Gaussian curve?

Tags: python, random

Currently, python has this integrated random algorithm:

> random.randint(0,x)

This function generates a random number from 0 to x. So far so good. The thing is, I want this algorithm to work in a way, that 0 has a larger chance to fall, then one, then all the way up to x, like an half Gaussian curve, where instead of the average being in the center, 0 is. Also I was thinking of an exponential decrease rather than linear. Do such algorithms exist in python?

Comment: This is a very common thing to do in Monte Carlo sampling. Every distribution can be described using it's Probability Density Function (PDF) for example Gaussian, but it also has a Cumulative Density Function. Using the [Inverse Transform Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) you can sample randomly between `0` and `1`, then sample back out of your desired distribution. Hopefully that is enough to get you started on some Googling, because covering all of that is too broad to try to cover in a Stack Overflow answer.

Comment: use [numpy.random.choice](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.random.choice.html). you can specify probabilities of each value with argument `p`.

Answer (score 3):

The [scipy.stats](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/stats.html#continuous-distributions) module has lots of probability functions to choose from. For example:

```
import scipy.stats as stats
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = stats.expon.rvs(size=10000)
plt.hist(x, 70, histtype="stepfilled", alpha=.7);
```

[image]

Comment: Sneaky, ninja-importing seaborn in there to make your plots look a bit nicer. :)

Comment: @Hooked, guilty, :-). BTW +1 for your nice pure python solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should really look into `scipy.stats` as @elyase mentions, but if you want a pure python solution, you can sample from a gaussian using the Box-Muller transform and only keep the points >= 0 to have your so-called "demi-gaussian":

```
import math
import random

def gaussian():
    # Uses a Box-Muller Transform to sample the standard normal
    # using two random numbers uniformly distributed on [0,1]
    u = random.random() 
    v = random.random()
    r  = (-2*math.log(u))**(.5)
    r *= math.cos(2*math.pi*v)
    return r

def demi_gaussian():
    # Keep sampling until we get a value >= 0
    while True:
        r  = gaussian()
        if r >= 0: 
            return r

import pylab as plt
R = [demi_gaussian() for _ in xrange(100000)]
plt.hist(R,70,histtype="stepfilled",alpha=.7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The comments of @pjs note that this solution can be speed up by a factor of two or four by noting that the Box-Muller transform gives you two gaussian numbers for each call and that a gaussian with mean zero is symmetrically centered about the origin (so we need not reject, just return the negative). These are valid points, and can be incorporated into a more sophisticated answer -- the solution above was intentionally simple to illustrate how to sample your distribution.

Comment: Several nits to pick with your solution.  1) Use `math.pi` rather than a limited precision literal you typed in.  2) Box-Muller uses two uniforms to produce two independent Gaussians by evaluating both cosine and sine of the randomly generated angle.  You're throwing away half of the potential values by not returning a tuple.  3) In the `demi_gaussian` function there's no need to reject and loop if you get a negative Gaussian - since the Gaussian is symmetric you can just return the absolute value.

Comment: @pjs All valid points -- it was a quick one off to demonstrate the solution.  1] I agree, and I'll change it over. 2] I realize that I was throwing away half of the computation, this was done for pedagogic reasons so OP could see the clear chain of a single output. 3] This is only true for the case of a symmetric function about zero. While True here, I felt like I should illustrate the general Monte-Carlo method of rejection. Thanks for the input!